# Exception sending mail via SmtpClient

Tags: c#, smtp

I want to create a SMTP server with auth on my windows system. For testing reasons I don't want to download another SMTP tool from the internet, so I try to sent an email directly in code to (only for debugging). My code at the moment:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;

namespace smttest
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
        NetworkCredential basicCredential = 
        new NetworkCredential("username", "password"); 
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage(); 
        MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress("from@dnet.com");

        smtpClient.Port = 26;
        smtpClient.Host = "localhost";
        smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtpClient.Credentials = basicCredential;

        message.From = fromAddress;
        message.Subject = "testmail";
        //Set IsBodyHtml to true means you can send HTML email.
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;
        message.Body = "testmail from sharp";
        message.To.Add(new MailAddress("my@email.com"));

        try
        {
            smtpClient.Send(message);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //Error, could not send the message
            Console.Write(ex.Message);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }


    }
}
}
```

The cmd just shows me: Error while sending email(translated from German). I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Am I missing something? All that code is related to an SMTP Client whereas your issue presumably lies with your server implementation ...

Comment: You want to create an SMTP *server*?  Why on Earth would you do that?  That's *a lot* of work for a product that already exists in spades.  Also, the code you posted isn't an SMTP server.  It's *using* an SMTP server.  If you wrote that server, and that server isn't sending email, the problem would be *on that server*.  Not in the code which sends requests to it.

Comment: Is it catching an exception? Can you give the full stack trace if so.

Comment: Change `Console.Write(ex.Message);` to a more informative `Console.Write(ex);` and check the output.

Answer (score 0):

You are using localhost as your SMTP server. Is it an email server? If not, you cannot use SMTPClient to send email. You need an SMTP server like smtp.google.com

Answer (score -1):

I was a bit confused. I need an e-mail (SMTP) server with auth (simple user/pass) running in C# to sent e-mails using another software called 'MaxBulkMailer'. The SMTP server in c# should just run on cmd, without GUI stuff.

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly as this does not answer your question.